# Why Tokenizer is keeping track of more words than num_words?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

sentences = [
             'I love my dog',
             'I love my cat',
             'You love my dog',
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=3)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

print(word_index)
```

> Output: {'love': 1, 'my': 2, 'i': 3, 'dog': 4, 'cat': 5, 'you': 6}

Now how my code is keeping track of more than 3 unique frequent words?

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py), it seems as though indices are assigned to all words encountered. However, once you actually use the tokenizer to convert text to index sequences (e.g. using `texts_to_sequences`), all "infrequent words" will be replaced by the OOV token. Note that this will only be done if you actually specify an OOV token (which you haven't). Examples:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

sentences = [
             'I love my dog',
             'I love my cat',
             'You love my dog dog',
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=4, oov_token=None)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

print(word_index)
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(["I love my cat"])
```

> {'love': 1, 'you': 6, 'i': 4, 'dog': 3, 'my': 2, 'cat': 5}
>   [[1, 2]]

I slightly modified the text to break the tie between "dog" and "I" and increased the number of stored words by one (for whatever reason, specifying 4 actually only uses the three most common words...). You can see that OOV words ("I" and "cat") are simply left out of the text even though they have an index assigned.

Here's what happens if we specify an OOV token:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

sentences = [
             'I love my dog',
             'I love my cat',
             'You love my dog dog',
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=4, oov_token="oov")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

print(word_index)
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(["I love my cat"])
```

> {'love': 2, 'you': 7, 'i': 5, 'dog': 4, 'my': 3, 'cat': 6, 'oov': 1}
>   [[1, 2, 3, 1]]

As you can see, index 1 is now reserved for the OOV token and infrequent words are assigned to this index when converted.